# angular ngFor display 3 buttons per row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am trying to display 3 buttons per div class="row".  I am using *ngFor to iterate through the array to display the buttons with the correct button text.

below is a sample of my data:
[{"NODE_ID":21.0,"NODE_DESC":"TERMINAL ASSEMBLY","GRPSEQNO":1.0},
{"NODE_ID":22.0,"NODE_DESC":"DR CORE ASSEMBLY","GRPSEQNO":2.0},{"NODE_ID":23.0,"NODE_DESC":"WINDING","GRPSEQNO":3.0},{"NODE_ID":25.0,"NODE_DESC":"SOLDERING","GRPSEQNO":1.0},
{"NODE_ID":24.0,"NODE_DESC":"ARRANGING PROCESS BEFORE SOLDERING","GRPSEQNO":2.0},{"NODE_ID":29.0,"NODE_DESC":"HEIGHT INSPECTION","GRPSEQNO":3.0}]

the layout that i want to achieve is :
[button layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaudR.png)

I cannot produce this layout.  Please help.  Thank you in advance.

I have created a stackblitz which I am currently doing
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wipq2r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Try to avoid using images when posting and instead post the code you've already tried.

Comment: Pls, can you share your code ? or create example in stackBlitz.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AldinBradaric. Sorry about that.  I will avoid to post images

Comment: @DanielVágner I have shared the code in stackBlitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wipq2r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @ddb20 I've forked your code and made some changes 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wipq2r-8srzgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.css

Comment: @SaraStoimenovska Thank you very much it solved my problem.

Comment: @SaraStoimenovska Is there any way that I can put an image or text in between the gaps like an arrow using the css grid?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

In Productlist.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of procDesc; let i = index">
    <div class="row">
        <button  type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs col-md-12 btn-block"
          style="margin-bottom:4px; word-wrap:break-word; color: white">
          <span style="font-size:smaller; color: white">{{ procDesc[i].NODE_DESC
          }}</span>
        </button>&nbsp;
        <!-- <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs col-md-12 btn-block"
          style="margin-bottom:4px; word-wrap:break-word; color: white">
          <span style="font-size:smaller; color: white">{{
            procDesc[i].NODE_DESC
          }}</span>
        </button>&nbsp;
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs col-md-12 btn-block"
          style="margin-bottom:4px; word-wrap:break-word; color: white">
          <span style="font-size:smaller; color: white">{{
            procDesc[i].NODE_DESC
          }}</span>
        </button> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in productlist.css

```
.btn {
  white-space: normal !important;
  padding: 0.5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
:host {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  Can you do it with fixed button sizes so it looks uniform?

Comment: yes that could be done, set button width to a fixed size

Comment: something like this .btn {
  white-space: normal !important;
  padding: 0.5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
}

Comment: Updated styles in my answer, let me know.

Comment: Request you to mark the answer as completed, if it has served your purpose. Thanks